# Server under attack website logs \x80w\x01\x03\x01 and HNAP1 how do I stop bot?

Tags: php, mysql, security, httprequest

I'm on bluehost with a shared server;  mysql  5.5.36 -with an empty database.. Apache 2.2.26, php version 5.4.24, x86_64, linus, perl Can you guys tell me what this means?  My access logs show this unsavory behavior:

```
[ip]71.63.199.72 [url]HNAP1 [size] 134 [status] 401 [method]GET [protocol] HTTP/1.1 [referring url] My server address
[ip]71.63.199.72 [url]401 [size] 0 [status] 0 [method]\x80w\x01\x03\x01 [protocol] 162 [referring url] none
[ip]141.212.121.10 [url]404 [size] 0 [status] 0 [method]\x16\x03\x01
[protocol] 406 [referring url] none
```

Any help would be appreciated. **How do I stop this?** Is something enticing hackers? I had to password protect directories (don't know if that helps) but I need to take passwords off and make sure this hacker's request are not honored. **1.How do I learn about these request? 2.what is he after? 3. what is it called?**

Also, I have cloudflare but this guy seems to bypass them. I have no threats in my cloudflare but the stuff above shows in my sites 'latest visitor logs.' Is that because the hacker has direct server access?  I can follow directions really well if someone will point me the right way.

Comment: Maybe you need something like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/) to block anyone harassing you like this. Drive-by attacks like this are just part of having a server on the public internet.

Comment: That's usually just automated probing targetting no server in particular; [Strange requests to web server](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/40291)

Comment: yeah I'm with @mario .. Make sure that these probes don't detect vulnerabilities like weak passwords, hidden test files, ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking at is a malformed request. In other words, the server didn't understand the SSL handshake (probably because you don't have it installed/enabled). You'll note the previous method was `method GET`, where the server understood the handshake. The code you're seeing is the standard start of the handshake

https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/CSAM+Web+Honeypot+Logs/16718

> SSL Conection to a web server not supporting SSL
>
> Invalid method in request \x80w\x01\x03\x01
>
> The first few bytes of the request are interpreted as the method of
>   the request. If SSL is used by the client, but the server "doesn't get
>   it", then the server will just log the first few bytes of the SSL
>   message. In this case, this was \x80w\x01\x03\x01

Comment: @Machavity Thanks for the answer! I had to nuke my cpanel because this guy was getting in and changing the configuration of my site. I erased everything! I want to keep him out so how do I prevent him getting in again?  Before, I had an ssl installed.  So, in trying to understand this should I read up on http request? I'd like to learn.

Comment: Thanks for the honeypot info too!

Comment: You can always block the IP within CloudFlare itself, provided you're not bypassing the filter.

Answer (score 1):

If the annoying bot works from the single IP, under Linux it is trivial to block it with IPTables:

```
 iptables -I INPUT -s 123.321.123.321 -j DROP
```

where 123.321.123.321 is a sample misbehaving address.